# Query to fetch detail of user

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

This is my [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30321/25) which generates following table

```
SELECT user_messages.messageid,user_messages.message,
user_messages.sentby,user_messages.visibility,

(
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `post_images`.`image_id` SEPARATOR ';')
    FROM  `post_images`
    JOIN user_messages
  ON `post_images`.`messageid` =user_messages.messageid
) AS  `Image_post_id`,
(
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `post_images`.`small_pic_path` SEPARATOR ';')
    FROM  `post_images`
    JOIN user_messages
  ON `post_images`.`messageid` =user_messages.messageid
) AS Small_pic_path,
(
  SELECT count(*) FROM likes
  WHERE element_id=user_messages.messageid
  )AS Total_Likes

FROM user_messages
WHERE user_messages.userid='1';
```

[image: Sql table]

Here I want to include detail of **sentby** which is id in smsusers table.
I want details fname,lname from smsusers table,and small_pic_path from profile_pic table.
How to fetch Details.

Comment: Please always post your code here, rather than driving us off to an external link

Comment: Yes I got your point. Thanks for editing I was not able to put image there

Comment: Your image did not display properly because the image link was indented 4 spaces, which caused it to be interpreted as a code block.  I just removed the indentation and it showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  user_messages.messageid,
        user_messages.message,
        user_messages.sentby,
        user_messages.visibility,
        (
            SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(  `post_images`.`image_id` SEPARATOR ';')
            FROM    `post_images`
                    JOIN user_messages
                        ON `post_images`.`messageid` =user_messages.messageid
        )   AS  `Image_post_id`,
        (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  `post_images`.`small_pic_path` SEPARATOR ';')
            FROM  `post_images`
            JOIN user_messages
                ON `post_images`.`messageid` =user_messages.messageid
        ) AS Small_pic_path,
        (
            SELECT count(*) 
            FROM likes
            WHERE element_id=user_messages.messageid
        ) AS Total_Likes, 
        smsusers.*  -- select the columns you want to show
FROM    user_messages
        INNER JOIN smsusers 
        ON user_messages.SENTBY = smsusers.id
WHERE   user_messages.userid= '1';
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30321/26)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Visual Representation of SQL Joins this is very important likn for me thank you

Comment: you people are great.These are not much dificult(after getting solution) but I never faced such problems. till now i fetched data from only 2-3 tables,and only single values not multiple. Thanks alot.